# Purchase Inside App xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an ios app for a restaurant who has take out delivery. According to Apple's guidelines i cant use an In-app purchase for this.. I dont think. How Can I go about having the user submit a request(the order) and pay inside the app with a credit card?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, Apple doesn't allow the use of in-app purchasing for physical goods or products. However, you also **wouldn't want to use this anyways**... other processors are much less expensive than the 30% cut that Apple takes on IAP.

Instead, you should use a third party credit card processor and library:

[PayPal](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/how-to-guides/how-accept-payments-ios-app-using-mpl)

[Authorize.net](https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios)

Or another such processor.

Good Luck